# pushing multiple values to the same database location without overwriting existing data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I append new values to an array in realtime database, for example appending new images urls to an array.

```
"1":{
   "title":"some title",
   "imgs": [
        "https://img1",
        "https://img2",
        "https://img3",
        "https://img4"
    ]

}
```

the **push()** methods adds unique keys which I dont want.

This does overwrite all the data in the imgs array:

```
set(ref(db, postId +'/imgs'), {
    document.getElementById('input_img_url').value,
})
```

Comment: Have you tried to use update(), instead of set()?